Number of roots of complex polynomial
In the textbook I am studying from, fundamental theorem of algebra is given as any polynomial
$P(z) =a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2+.....+a_nz^n$ ($a_n \neq 0$)
of degree n ($n\geq 1$) has at least one zero.
But my professor stated the theorem as:
Any such polynomial has exactly n roots, unique/repeated roots all included.
Which is the correct version of this theorem? Are both statements true?

Both statements are equivalent.

One classically proves the one zero version, then says for your $P(z)$ that if it has a root $r$ you can divide it by $z-r$ without remainder and get a new polynomial.  Since that one has a root...

This post is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271563

Both statements are true. The second one is somewhat stronger than the first, and can be easily derived from it.
In my experience it's the second that's usually meant by "the fundamental theorem of algebra" but it's not wrong to say that about the first.
